# Update value in json file from commandline by preserving formatting and comments

Tags: json, linux, visual-studio-code, jq

I am trying to update some values in my Visual Studio Code `settings.json` from command line to be used in some desktop shortcuts and scripts in my Linux desktop. I was going to use `jq` but it looks like it doesn't support comments and some people recommend trimming comments beforehand but I want to preserve formatting, order and comments. Any simple way how to achieve this?

Comment: As you said, `jq` cannot handle comments&preserve formatting, use another tool like `awk/sed/...`

Comment: JSON itself (on purpose) doesn't implement comments, see https://www.json.org/

Comment: @pmf I know JSON spec doesn't support comments, but this doesn't really help

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Could you address whatever use-case you have by using [profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76#_profiles)?

Comment: @user I don't think profiles is a good solution in my case but I wasn't aware of this feature so thanks. So in Linux VSCode doesn't auto switch to dark mode and I found out it is an Electron bug(?). I have an auto theme changer GNOME plugin installed and can run commands on theme switch so I was going to change the `workbench.colorTheme` field.

Comment: If you just want to toggle themes, why not use VS Code's `Preferences: Toggle Between Light/Dark Themes` command? You can configure your default light and dark themes in the settings. You can even bind it to a keyboard shortcut using the `workbench.toggleLightDarkThemes` command ID.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/) doesn't implement comments (it used to back in the day but the author disliked that they were abused for providing processing instructions).

I don't know how Visual Studio Code implements the comments but if they use a hashmark sign `#` then you could consider treating the file as YAML instead. JSON is a subset of YAML (i.e. all JSON data is valid YAML), and YAML allows comments using hashmarks. Some suggestions:

- [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) is a YAML processor written in Python, and built on top of `jq`. It converts the YAML file into JSON (dropping the comments), then uses `jq` under the hood for processing (i.e. your filter can retain its `jq` syntax).
- [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) is a `jq` rewrite in Go that also implements YAML import and export functionalities. It is mostly compatible with `jq`, so you'd need to alter your filters only in certain edge cases.
- [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) is a standalone processor for YAML, JSON, and some other formats, also written in Go. It tries to adhere to the `jq` syntax but doesn't try to be fully compliant, so expect some adjustments to your filters.

If you provide some sample input, your desired output, and a `jq` filter that would accomplish it if comments weren't present, we can help to convert it using one of these tools.

Comment: JSON uses `{}` to mark objects, YAML uses indentation to mark objects, how can a YAML parser parse a JSON file

Comment: @rioV8 YAML allows various types of formatting. Since [YAML 1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/), one of them matches the JSON specs. Try out `yq . input.json`.